# In US v. Google (2020), how were the trial exhibits obtained?

Tags: united-states, antitrust-law

Here're the exhibits: https://www.justice.gov/atr/us-and-plaintiff-states-v-google-llc-2020-trial-exhibits

We see multiple emails and powerpoint slides - but how did DoJ obtain them in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably through some combination of:

1. subpoenas prior to commencing the lawsuit by the U.S. Department of Justice, state attorneys-general, grand juries, and/or state and federal regulatory agencies such as the Fair Trade Commission (FTC) which is the leading anti-trust regulator in the federal government (the case was brought jointly by the Department of Justice and state attorneys-general),
2. mandatory disclosures of documents pursuant to Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 26 that is required for parties to federal lawsuits,
3. requests for production of documents in written discovery requests issued in the lawsuit to other parties in the lawsuit pursuant to Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 34 within the limitations and structure of a case management order adopted pursuant to Federal Rule of Civil Procedure 16, and
4. subpoenas issued during discovery during the pendency of the lawsuit to third-parties.

Of course, it could have also obtained some documents outside the formal court process through the cooperation of friendly witnesses, regulatory filings, information available to the general public on websites, news reports, and the like.

There are also summaries of evidence prepared by their own lawyers and paralegals (called "demonstrative exhibits"), and some of the exhibits may have been prepared by their own expert witnesses.

The full text of the Federal Rules of Civil Procedure, as of December 1, 2022, are available [here](https://www.uscourts.gov/file/64234/download).